# Highly Available AMQP via Spring Integration and RabbitMQ - Issue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

**WHAT I DID:**

I am using RabbitMQ message broker which supports the AMQP standard in my spring micro services. Its main purpose is to prevent the message losing, during the rabbitMQ server (unfortunate) shutdown. So I am planning to give the Highly Available AMQP Backed Message Channels.

I tried to setup two RabbitMQ servers and I followed the below link to setup the RabbitMQ servers.

https://dzone.com/articles/highly-available-amqp-backed

**First RabbitMQ Server’ s config file(rabbitmq.config)** is as follows. It should be put under ../rabbitmq_server-version/etc/rabbitmq/

```
[
 {rabbit, [ {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
 {collect_statistics_interval, 10000},
 {heartbeat,30},
 {cluster_partition_handling, pause_minority},
 {cluster_nodes, {[ 'rabbit@master',
                    'rabbit2@master'],
                  disc}} ] },
 {rabbitmq_management, [ {http_log_dir,"/tmp/rabbit-mgmt"},{listener, [{port, 15672}]} ] },
 {rabbitmq_management_agent, [ {force_fine_statistics, true} ] }
].
```

**Second RabbitMQ Server’ s rabbitmq.config file :**

```
[
 {rabbit, [ {tcp_listeners, [5673]},
 {collect_statistics_interval, 10000},
 {heartbeat,30},
 {cluster_partition_handling, pause_minority},
 {cluster_nodes, {[ 'rabbit@master',
                    'rabbit2@master'],
                  disc}} ] },
 {rabbitmq_management, [ {http_log_dir,"/tmp/rabbit-mgmt"},{listener, [{port, 15673}]} ] },
 {rabbitmq_management_agent, [ {force_fine_statistics, true} ] }
].
```

**First RabbitMQ Server’ s sample bash script is** as follows. Also please have a look RabbitMQ Cluster documentation for other configuration steps.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "*** First RabbitMQ Server is setting up ***"

export RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME=rabbit@master
export RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@master
export RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15672}]"

/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2/sbin/rabbitmq-server &

echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server is set up succesfully. ***"

sleep 5

echo "*** First RabbitMQ Server' s status : ***"

/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2/sbin/rabbitmqctl status
```

**Second RabbitMQ Server’ s sample bash script is as follows :**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server is setting up ***"

export RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME=rabbit2@master
export RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit2@master
export RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15673}]"

/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2_2/sbin/rabbitmq-server &

echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server is set up succesfully. ***"

sleep 5

echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server' s status : ***"

/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2_2/sbin/rabbitmqctl status

sleep 5

echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server is being added to cluster... ***"

/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2_2/sbin/rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@master stop_app
/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2_2/sbin/rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@master join_cluster rabbit@master
/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2_2/sbin/rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@master start_app
/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2/sbin/rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@master set_policy ha-all "^ha\." '{"ha-mode":"all"}'

echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server is added to cluster successfully... ***"

sleep 5

echo "*** Second RabbitMQ Server' s cluster status : ***"

/DEV_TOOLS/rabbitmq_server-3.4.2_2/sbin/rabbitmqctl cluster_status
```

**WHAT IS ISSUE:**

I can see that two RabbitMQ servers are running synchronously.

When I stop the first node, the second node is working.

```
sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app
```

But When I shut down the first RabbitMQ server, the second node also going down.

```
sbin/rabbitmqctl stop
```

But, The result should be,

> If First Messaging Node and First RabbitMQ Server are shut down
>   accidentally, Second Messaging Node and Second RabbitMQ Server will
>   continue to process Order messages so potential message loosing and
>   service interruption problems can be prevented by using high available
>   AMQP backed channel.

Kindly help me to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: This question really has nothing at all to do with the spring projects you cite. You might have better luck with pure rabbitmq questions by directing them to the rabbitmq-users google group - that's where the rabbitmq engineers hang out.